# Interchange Connection string (Short cut to do something similar to Rename Refactoring)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have two connection strings saved in `Properties` that I need interchangeability.

One is for a `database` that is used to test my application and the other is for the actuall `database` that the application will be used on.

My problem is that I have to use the connection string many times in different classes and as it stands now I am manually changing to the connection string by copy and paste.

Is it possible to do something similar as [Rename Refactoring (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx) ,but not actually rename, but replace the connection string with the second one?

Ie, my first connection string is this,

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString_One))
```

Replace every connection string value into the second connection string,

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString_Two))
```

Comment: Find & Replace? Or do you suspect that there are unrelated uses of the names of the properties?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, no, no unrelated uses of the property. Where is find & replace?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, never mind I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One is for a database that is used to test my application and the
>   other is for the actuall database that the application will be used
>   on.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to replace the connection string in the production build. Here's the step how to do it.

1. Save the connection string in config file

Sample code: (**web.config OR app.config**)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="{testing}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

2. Create a **build transformation** (by default, it would have  `debug` build and `release` build
3. Replace the **testing connection string with production connection string in release build**

Sample code: (**web.release.config OR app.release.config**)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="ConnectionString" connectionString="{production}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Hope it helps.

Read more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I am still in testing phase , but have sent out the application for a few selected users to test for bugs and and I am switching in between databases when I need to try something that may be harmful to the actual database. So I need interchangeability between connection strings while I am doing this.

Comment: OR, are you suggesting that I publish a version that I change the string then?

Comment: @KyloRen: you can either make a published build, or you can **run locally under a specific build environment**, assuming you want to test something harmful, just switch to **testing** build environment and Visual Studio will take care the rest for you.

Comment: OK, I see what you are trying to tell me to do. Switch between debug and release builds and have the release build automatically have the connection string of the actual DB. Now , implementing this may be a little more difficult. I am going to UV and mark as solved, but if I ping you for a question , I would really appreciate it if you could respond back. Thanks again for the information.

Comment: OK, I am getting an error, `An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll` Any ideas?

Comment: The error has something to do with this. `xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"`

Comment: @KyloRen do you have any other error? can you screenshot/copy the full error log here?

Comment: This is the screen shot of the error, https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8590/28908077445_08ccfe9dd9_b.jpg                     It does have something to do with this`xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"`

Comment: @KyloRen: I couldn't understand Japanese, and please let me see the detailed error

Comment: This is the link to the exception, the Japanese can't be changed to English unfortunately. https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHTypeInitialization);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120676/discussion-between-kienct89-and-kyloren).